# How can I ignore implicitly any type when importing js module?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, brightcove

I am trying to import this [@brightcove/react-player-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@brightcove/react-player-loader) package into my typescript project but its not running due to type error.
[image]

I have tried overriding the module type in my custom.d.ts file like this but I couldnt get it to work:

```
import '@brightcove/react-player-loader';

declare module '@brightcove/react-player-loader' {
  var x: any;
  export = x;
}
```

I get this error:
[image]

Any ideas how can I resolved this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ran into this same error recently as well.

You can create a declaration file that fixes the error by doing the following:

1. Create an index.d.ts file in the root of your project
2. Add declare module "@brightcove/react-player-loader"; to the first line of the file
3. In your tsconfig.json file, in the "include" section, make sure you have an entry for .d.ts files, *e.g.*:

   ```
   "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.d.ts"]
   ```

This should get rid of the error you are experiencing.